# Stopping zsh from clearing the screen on each command

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

I use zsh on Mac OS X, with a theme based on "oh-my-zsh".

Each time I run a command, zsh "clears" the screen (really, inserting a few dozens newlines). This is very irritating, but I can't figure out how to turn this off.

What am I missing?

Comment: Ok, this is a bit weird. I decided to play with the zsh commands in ~/.oh-my-zsh. I arbitrarily commented out "alias history='fc -l 1'" from one of the included files, and suddenly the screen clearing stopped. This is positively weird, and I can't figure out why it'd have that effect. Enlightenment welcome.

Comment: Which oh-my-zsh theme are you using?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, commenting out the following from **~/.oh-my-zsh/lib/alias.zsh** will fix the problem:

```
alias history='fc -l 1'
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar troubles and found a solution by setting the TERM variable in my .zshrc file as so:

```
if [ `find /usr/share/terminfo -name "xterm-256color" -print` &> /dev/null ]; then
    export TERM='xterm-256color'
else
    export TERM='xterm'
fi
```

(No comment about using `xterm` over `rxvt`)